# How can I change the title of a control of a menu item in app which is not mine using c++ win32 api?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

For example, if I'll want to change to "Copy" string under "edit" menu on notepad.

I am trying to do the following:

use enumWindowsProc (works well)

```
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(
    __in  HWND hWnd,
    __in  LPARAM lParam
) {
    int length = ::GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    if (0 == length) return TRUE;

    TCHAR* buffer;
    buffer = new TCHAR[length + 1];
    memset(buffer, 0, (length + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));

    GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    wcout << buffer << endl;
    wstring s2(buffer);
    wstring s3(L"Notepad");
    std::string::size_type found = s2.find(s3);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, 0);
    }
    delete[] buffer;
    return TRUE;
}
```

and than use EnumChildProc (does not give the required behavior. I hoped to get a tree of controls):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    
    int length = ::GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    if (0 == length) return TRUE;

    TCHAR* buffer;
    buffer = new TCHAR[length + 1];
    memset(buffer, 0, (length + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));

    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, length + 1);
    OutputDebugString(buffer);
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");
    
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, EnumChildProc, 0);

    delete[] buffer;
    return TRUE;
    
}
```

Comment: Here is a hack: 1) Rename the target application to a backup name;  2) Open a new file, using the original name; 3) For the entire file, read in some data; if the data is not the string you want, write it to the output file. 4) Otherwise, modify the string, then write it and the remaining contents to the new file.  5) Close all files.  This method is a hack because it doesn't account for any checksums in the the executable, nor modification (e.g. compression) of the search text.

Comment: The hacking process may be faster by using a hex editor (a tool that can edit binary files).

Comment: Short answer is "You cannot". Longer answer is "Most things are possible, but you may have to find some novel ways to circumvent / exploit / hack  the system - under *normal* circumstances, one program should not be able to modify another".